# Jsoup Login aspx Digikey

Tags: java, parsing, post, authentication, jsoup

I have a problem with connect to Digikey.it with jsoup.
I need login with my account and use cookies, but when i execute post, do not login.
This is my code:

```
String UrlLogin="https://www.digikey.it/classic/RegisteredUser/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fclassic%2fregistereduser%2fmydigikey.aspx%3fsite%3dit%26lang%3dit&site=it&lang=it";

Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(UrlLogin)
                                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                                    .execute();

Document loginPage = response.parse();
response = Jsoup.connect(UrlLogin)
                .data("ctl00$ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$mainContentPlaceHolder$txtUsername", "username")
                .data("ctl00$ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$mainContentPlaceHolder$txtPassword", "password")
                .data("ctl00$ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$mainContentPlaceHolder$btnLogin", "Accesso")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .method(Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .execute()
doc = response.parse();
```

Who can help me?

Comment: Are you getting an error when you attempt to login? If so what is the specific error?

Comment: Hi Kmeixner, no error on execut. The status of response is OK. After login , the site should redirect to another page, but the Url of response don't change, and count of redirect is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log in with this code:

```
try {
            String urlLogin = "https://www.digikey.it/classic/RegisteredUser/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fclassic%2fregistereduser%2fmydigikey.aspx%3fsite%3dit%26lang%3dit&site=it&lang=it";
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();


            Document loginPage = response.parse();

            Element eventValidation = loginPage.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").first();
            Element viewState = loginPage.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").first();


            response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState.attr("value"))
                    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation.attr("value"))
                    .data("ctl00$ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$mainContentPlaceHolder$txtUsername", "username")
                    .data("ctl00$ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$mainContentPlaceHolder$txtPassword", "password")
                    .data("ctl00$ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$mainContentPlaceHolder$btnLogin", "Accesso")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .execute();

            Document document = response.parse();
            Element liElement = document.select("li#welcome_name").first();

            System.out.println(liElement.html());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Hi martic. Thanks for your solution. The problem is SOLVED!!